# tex4ht: conflict between `\[` `\]` environment and label, ref?

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

I try to compile the following very simple code by `tex4eboot`:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\[
  x=y\label{t1}\tag{Test}
\]
Look at equation \ref{t1}.
\end{document}
```

It gives me errors:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   5    Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   5    Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   5    Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.
```

However, I can use pdflatex to compile it.
I know that I can replace `\[` and `\]` by `equation`. However, since usually the article is long and a regexpr to replace will lead to unexpected results. I wonder a workaround for this. Thanks!

Comment: if you get an error please always show the exact error from the log, I get no error with pdflatex (as you say)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{[]}{\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It basically does the same thing as Amsmath, configures `\[ ... \]` to the `equation*` environment.

This is the result:

[image]

I've added this code to `tex4ht` sources, so it should be default behavior in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I found that in my configure file, it has a previous configuration like `RobustCommand` to treat `\[` as `\begin{equation*}`. Unfortunately, I deleted it so I cannot recover it now. What's the different between the two?

Comment: @Yai0Phah the `\RobustCommand` version could broke some things, it don't work for MathML for example. This version should be safer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `\[...\]` used for unnumbered display equation, if you change your code to `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, then your code works fine, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x=y\label{t1}\tag{Test}
\end{equation}
Look at equation \ref{t1}.
\end{document}
```

and the converted `HTML` output is:

[image]

Comment: It is very weird that `equation*` works but `\[` and `\]` don't work (I found it just after upgrade to the current version of tex4ht, previously `equation*` did not work). I know that `equation` always works, but since `\[` and `\]` work for pdflatex, I hope that it would be supported in tex4ht.

Comment: `michal.h21` already answered that he added this code to `tex4ht` sources...